# Correct Datatype for new field - list of timestamps

Tags: lightning, datetime, data-types

I'm just doing this using the Salesforce Lightning GUI, not doing it programmatically.

I am creating a new field for a Salesforce object. This field will hold multiple datetime stamps. When an event occurs, a datetime stamp will be appended to the field. It will effectively be a list of datetime stamps. I am confused as to which data type to use.

I am not sure that either date or date/time will capture multiple datetime stamps:
[image]

I suppose I could just use an open ended text field, but as these are datetime objects, we would like to use these as such (to see when was most recent event, etc) instead of just a text field.

Any suggestions for the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a list in a field, but instead you need to have a related list of objects that are children of the Salesforce object and that contain a single Datetime field.

For example, if your main object type is `MyObject__c`, you might have a new custom object called `MyObjectTimestamp__c`. This would have a Master Detail field referencing MyObject__c along with a `Timestamp__c` field of type Date/Time (which likely needs to be mandatory).

When the specific event occurs you simply create a new `MyObjectTimestamp__c` record, referencing the `MyObject__c` record for which the event occurred and setting the `Timestamp__c` field to "now".

This could be done in an "after update" trigger or via a flow or process builder as you see fit.

BTW, taking this approach means you can later add extra fields to the timestamp allowing more information to be recorded as well.

All the timestamps can be shown on the layout in a related list. It is even more flexible in Lightning Record Pages since you can use the single related list control in the page, and if using Dynamic Forms even interleave this with other data in the main Salesforce object's details.